# Perl: Change in Subroutine not printing outside of routine

Tags: perl, reference, argument-passing, subroutine

So I want to change numbers that I pass into a subroutine, and then retain those numbers being changed, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    my $A = 0;
    my $T = 0;
    my $C = 0;
    my $G = 0;   

     foreach my $bases in (keys %basereads){
          count ($bases, $A, $T, $C, $G);
    }
```

Here is my subroutine

```
    sub count {
    my $bases = shift;
    my $A = shift;
    my $T = shift;
    my $C = shift;
    my $G = shift;
            for (my $i = 0; $i < length($bases); $i++){
                    print "$bases\t";
                 if (uc(substr($bases,$i,1)) eq 'A'){
                               $A++;
                 }elsif (uc(substr($bases,$i,1)) eq 'T'){
                               $T++;
                 } elsif (uc(substr($bases,$i,1)) eq 'G'){
                               $G++;
                 } elsif (uc(substr($bases,$i,1)) eq 'C'){
                                $C++;
                 } else { next; }

           }
            print "$A\t$C\t$T\t$G\n";
    return my($bases, $A, $T, $C, $G);

    }
```

after the subroutine, I want to stored the altered A, C, T, G into a hashmap. When I print bases and ATCG inside the subroutine, it prints, so I know the computer is running through the subroutine, but it's not saving it, and when I try to manipulate it outside the subroutine (after I've called it), it starts from zero (what I had defined the four bases as before). I'm new to Perl, so I'm a little weary of subroutines.
    Could someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY script.

With `warnings` enabled, you should've gotten the following messages:

```
"my" variable $bases masks earlier declaration in same scope at script.pl line ...
"my" variable $A masks earlier declaration in same scope at script.pl line ...
"my" variable $T masks earlier declaration in same scope at script.pl line ...
"my" variable $C masks earlier declaration in same scope at script.pl line ...
"my" variable $G masks earlier declaration in same scope at script.pl line ...
```

These are caused by the [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) before your [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) statement:

```
return my($bases, $A, $T, $C, $G);
```

Correct this by simply removing the `my`:

```
return ($bases, $A, $T, $C, $G);
```

And then you just need to capture your returned values

```
($bases, $A, $T, $C, $G) = count($bases, $A, $T, $C, $G);
```

Given that you're new to perl, I'm sure you won't be surprised that your code could be cleaned up further though.  If one uses a hash, it makes it a lot easier to count various characters in a string, as demonstrated below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $A = 0;
my $T = 0;
my $C = 0;
my $G = 0;   

foreach my $bases (keys %basereads) {
    my %counts;
    for my $char (split //, $bases) {
        $counts{$char}++;
    }
    $A += $counts{A};
    $T += $counts{T};
    $C += $counts{C};
    $G += $counts{G};
}
```

Comment: and a lot easier to leave them in a hash rather than four separate variables

Comment: @ysth For sure.  But in order to educate, it helps to leave at least some semblance to the original code.  ;)  Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: NP.  Feel free to give this solution the check mark if it answers your question.